# How to direct to a VMs hosted homepage using a bridge?

Tags: networking, ubuntu, router, apache-http-server

**Scenario (Ubuntu Server 16.04)**:

A server is located via a static ip: eg 192.168.178.79. The servers networking is configured as a bridge:

ifconfig shows:

```
br0       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b0:5a:da:87:9a:ec  
          inet addr:192.168.178.79  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::b25a:daff:fe87:9aec/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1138 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1543 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:121101 (121.1 KB)  TX bytes:3243595 (3.2 MB)

em1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr b0:5a:da:87:9a:ec  
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:1172 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2602 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:153356 (153.3 KB)  TX bytes:3324020 (3.3 MB)
          Interrupt:16 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:2734 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2734 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:1305517 (1.3 MB)  TX bytes:1305517 (1.3 MB)
```

A virutal machine within this server is using a static ip 192.168.178.51 and its

ipconfig shows:

```
ens3      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 52:54:00:15:9f:c0  
          inet addr:192.168.178.51  Bcast:192.168.178.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5054:ff:fe15:9fc0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:181 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:142 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:136824 (136.8 KB)  TX bytes:15128 (15.1 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)  TX bytes:11840 (11.8 KB)
```

The server is currently running apache2 with two working websites on 80 and 443 ports. They are reachable because i opened the ports via the router.

First concern: I dont understand, why the server has "no" internet connection. Eg:

sudo apt update

Is not working and i am only able to ping the local network addresses. Whats wrong here?

Now i want to setup a new homepage using apache2 on my virtual machine, but if i set it up. It is not reachable, because i am not able to open the 80 and 443 port for 192.168.178.51 (the vm) on my router because it is already used by the server 192.168.178.79. I guess i have to redirect something at 192.168.178.79 so it gets forwarded to 192.168.178.51?

Any help is welcome! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of questions:

1. Why no update? Probably no default route. See http://www.wikihow.com/Add-or-Change-the-Default-Gateway-in-Linux
2. You can't really host two webservers on the same outside address. I would suggest an alternate port for one of the web servers -- frequently 81 or 8080. This would make the URL http://myhost.com:81 You would need to forward that port in your router.

Tom...

Comment: Thank's for helping me out. I checked the gateway and it should be fine. route command looks good to me.
What i do not understand is, why i can not have to alternative webservers on the same port. I mean if my router directs incomming webrequests on port 80 or 443 and notices that they are from webaddress xyz.com there should be a way to redirect them to another local ip (eg. the vms ip) where the second webserver gets the request and answers through the servers ip (forwarding?) in the www.